# KeyError: "@" in python

Tags: python, keyerror

\When I train a machine learning model, I get 3 KeyError. But I haven't found the reason. Do you know how to avoid this error?

```
def encode(sm_list, pad_size=50):
"""
Encoder list of smiles to tensor of tokens
"""
res = []
lens = []
for s in sm_list:
    tokens = ([1] + [__t2i[tok] 
         for tok in smiles_tokenizer(s)])[:pad_size - 1]  (the error line)
    lens.append(len(tokens))
    tokens += (pad_size - len(tokens)) * [2]
    res.append(tokens)

return torch.tensor(res).long(), lens


def smiles_tokenizer(line, atoms=None):
    if atoms is not None:
    reg = get_tokenizer_re(atoms)
else:
    reg = _atoms_re
return reg.split(line)[1::2]
```

and

```
__t2i = {
'>': 1, '<': 2, '2': 3, 'F': 4, 'Cl': 5, 'N': 6, '[': 7, '6': 8,
'O': 9, 'c': 10, ']': 11, '#': 12, '=': 13, '3': 14, ')': 15,
'4': 16, '-': 17, 'n': 18, 'o': 19, '5': 20}
```

I use the function as

```
 enc_out = self.enc.encode(x_batch)
```

it throws the error: KeyError:"@", What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you fix the formatting? there are multiple indentation issues in your code.

Comment: And post the full error traceback together with a [mre]

Comment: Anyway as you showed, `__t2i` doesn't have `@` as a key and your input does apparently. Can't see how we can help as we don't know what is `x_batch` nor `smiles_tokenizer`